# Display User Input onChange

Tags: javascript, onchange

I'm trying to get a numerical user input to display elsewhere on the page through an id whenever the input box is changed, but it just won't work. Here's what I've been using

```
        function updateTotalCashPaid() {
            var x;
            var cashInput = document.getElementById("cashPaid").value;
            x = cashInput;
            document.getElementbyId("totalCashPaid").innerHTML = x;
        }   

<p style="padding-left:10%"><input type="Number" id="cashPaid" name="cashPaid" step=".01" min="0" onchange="updateTotalCashPaid()"></p>


<p id="totalCashPaid" style="display: inline; ">replace with User Input</p>
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what happens after the function runs?

Comment: The numbers stay in the box and nothing else happens.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5NCW9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a simply typo. Instead of `getElementById`, you have `getElementbyId` at `document.getElementbyId("totalCashPaid").innerHTML = x;`

Comment: You are welcome.By the way if this solves your issue why not mark it as the answer?